# In JHipster: how to change database settings after creation?

Tags: jhipster

Is there a way to modify the Jhispster settings after the project has been created? For example, let's say we want to change the...

```
Which *development* database would you like to use? H2 with in-memory persistence
```

from in-memory back to disk-based persistance.

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just modify the .yo-rc.json and regenerate the project with `jhipster --force`

Comment: I did find .yo-rc.json config file and rerun the application, but didn't know I have to run this `jhipster --force` command. What actually this command do?

Comment: It regenerates your whole application, more info here: https://www.jhipster.tech/creating-an-app/